Anime/Live Action about people using robot/mecha to fight monsters/aliens
Key feature of the series or movie is that it combines japanese anime styled characters and live action backgrounds.
Predates 90's or is very early 90's.
Basic premise is that humans use a robot/mecha/giant vehicle that is crewed by several people(at least one girl among them) to fight some kind of monster/alien.
I remember only one scene: the crew is crashlanded in a city in either some kind of vehicle or robot sitting in two rows seats while the monster rampages across the city and one of the male characters is depressed over something(iirc his friend/love interest died). The rest of the crew tell him to get over himself - they're gonna fight with or without him.
During this scene the overall pallete is dark blue. Characters wear uniform resembling that of pilots from early macross(at least in combat).
Can't remember if it was a series or a movie.
IIRC the crew piloted the robot from a single cockpit which excludes a lot of Super-sentais.
Overall impression about the picture was that it was very grim genre where characters died and there was little space for humor. But maybe it's not true since I was a kid back then.

Is this something maybe a la Pacific Rim?

Not Pacific Rim. It's a very old(imho pre 90's) and animation means drawn cartoon ala japanese style(don't know if it's actually japanese).

I know, that's why I said it is like :)

Sounds a lot like Tenggen Toppa Gurren Lagann. But that is from 2007 i think.

@Dexter If you're about the part where someone dies(Kamina) then that's probably the only common thing I can think of. Gurren Lagan is quite positive minus the death arc.

Ah that's what i get for skimming. Yes you are right it is mostly not grim. Quite a few deaths towards the end though... some really really heartbreaking deaths...

How certain is the live-action part. Or is it rotoscoped etc?

BTW my first thought is "Blue Gender" but it is 1999 or so and has no live action. It is pretty bleak throughout, and while there are primarily one-pilot mecha, there are a lot of other transport vehicles featured. It is a series, so the plot point you mention may be buried in there, and they may have been in a transport or tank etc. for that. Lots of ruined cities. I don't think I saw the whole run, just a few episodes.

I found it! It's "Dinosaur War Izenborg" franchise. Originally a series of 39 episodes it was complied several times under different names as Attack of the Super Monsters or I-ZENBORG in different countries.
Turns out it's Dinosaurus and not monsters/aliens and vehicles instead of robots, they do sit in two row seats cockpits to control them and have uniform.
